# Bundling of index.js is taking forever in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

I'm currently working on a **react-native** project in which bundling of `index.js` file is taking forever.

First, I thought it was in development mode but even after creating an `APK`, It shows splash screen for almost 1 minute and sometimes it passes 2 minutes.

**What I have tried:**
I also removed splash screen thinking it was the issue in splash screen. But after removing splash screen it shows white screen for the same time it was showing splash screen. I have tried researching after it but found no solution at all.

This is the step where it get stuck for up-to 2 mins even in release APK:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:
It was due to a package taking forever to initialize itself.

Comment: It's not an answer it just a comment

Comment: what is the "a package".  Maybe we also have that package and we may need to uninstall it for a solution.

Comment: Package was a private package.